# Taylor Polynomials in Rudin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Rudin phrases **Taylor's Theorem** in the following way:

> *Suppose $f$ is a real function on $[a, b]$, $n$ is an integer, $f^{(n-1)}$ continuous on $[a, b]$, $f^{(n)}(t)$ exists for every $t \in (a, b)$. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be distinct points of $[a, b]$, and define
>   \begin{equation}
> P(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(\alpha)}{k!}(t - \alpha)^k
> \end{equation}
>   Then there exists a point $x$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
>   \begin{equation}\tag{*}
> f(\beta) = P(\beta) + \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(\beta - \alpha)^n
> \end{equation}*

It seems to me then that $f^{(n)}(\alpha) =\lim_{x \to \alpha}f^{(n)}(x) = 0$, simply by shuffling terms across and using repeated l'Hopitals, on (*).

Specifically, since $\beta \to \alpha$ forces $x \to \alpha$, from (*)
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \alpha}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} &= \lim_{\beta \to \alpha}\frac{f(\beta) - P(\beta)}{(\beta - \alpha)^n}\\
&= \lim_{\beta \to \alpha}\frac{f'(\beta) - P'(\beta)}{n(\beta - \alpha)^{n-1}}\\
&= \ldots\\ 
&= \frac{1}{n!}\lim_{\beta \to \alpha}(f^{(n)}(\beta) - P^{(n)}(\beta))\\
&= 0
\end{align}
by l'Hopital. Hence $f^{(n)}(\alpha) = \lim_{x \to \alpha}f^{(n)}(x) = 0$. What is wrong?

Comment: How are you taking the limit? Can you show us your steps? Remember that the claim is "there exists **a** point."

Comment: Hopefully it is more clear now?

Comment: Isn't the $n$-th derivative of $P_n$ zero?

Comment: Yes, thank you. The reason I asked this question was simply to compare the proof of Taylor's Theorem on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), with Rudin's formulation. Thank you